# ¿Cómo puedo realizar la siguiente query utilizando el ORM de Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

Qué tal, quisiera saber si pueden ayudarme a generar las sentencias con el ORM de Django de la siguiente query. He estado revisando la documentación y ejemplos, pero creo que no hay como un método "jerárquico" que me permita construir todo paso a paso.

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

```
SELECT 
    prod.id,
    prod.name, 
    prod.cost_iva,
    prod.description,
    prov.name AS provider_name,
    comp.name AS company_name,
    prod.brand,
    prod.maker,
    prod.cost,
    prod.suggested_price,
    prod.sku,
    prod.barcode,
    prod.stock,
    prod.width,
    prod.height,
    prod.depth,
    prod.weight,
    prod.shipping_width,
    prod.shipping_height,
    prod.shipping_depth,
    prod.shipping_weight,
    prod.deleted_at
FROM products AS prod
   INNER JOIN providers AS prov
ON prod.provider_id = prov.id
   INNER JOIN companies AS comp
ON prod.company_id = comp.id;
```

Comment: Suponiendo que tu modelo se llama `Product` podría ser así `Product.objects.all().select_related('companies', 'providers')` intenta ver qué consulta te arroja. Debes poner el nombre de los campos que son, yo puse `companies` y `providers` porque no sé como los definiste tu porque no agregaste el modelo

Comment: Esa sentencia ya la había probado, y es quizá la más cercana a lo que yo quiero, pero me trae todos los campos de cada tabla relacionada. A diferencia de la query yo quiero, en la que obtengo campos específicos de cada tabla.

Comment: Y ya intentaste usando la consulta con [.only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#only)?

Comment: Y para la parte del renombrado de campos puedes usar [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate)

Comment: ¿Pero como puedo usar only cuando adquiero los datos relacionados? Al parecer no functiona, me aparece el siguiente mensaje: Product.provider cannot be both deferred and traversed using select_related at the same time.

Comment: Intentaste usar `only` sin `select_related`? Recuerda de la forma `company__name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más óptimo en el ORM de Django sería usar `select_related()`:

```
Product.objects.all().select_related('companies', 'providers')
```

Si usas `only()` cargarás los campos que indiques de forma inmediata, pero los que no indiques se cargarán en diferido. Si quieres únicamente obtener los campos que indicas y ninguno más, tienes que usar [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) o [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).

```
Product.objects.select_related('companies', 'providers').values('name','provider__name')
```

La primera Query es suficiente, no vas a obtener diferencia de rendimiento con la última.

Comment: Hola Jota, según la documentación de Django el uso de `prefetch_related` está asociado a relaciones de tipo muchos a muchos, y esta realiza dos consultas a partir del query completo, sólo es válida en el caso que estés recorriendo cada producto e intentaras acceder a algo como `producto.companies.all()` por lo que cambia la consulta inicial que quiere hacer el OP, además que según los datos que proporciona en la consulta, se está refiriendo a una relación de un elemento, es decir `select_related`

Comment: Jota fue quien me dió la solución al problema, al final la sentencia en el ORM quedó de la siguiente forma: 

all_products = Product.objects.select_related("provider", "company").values("id", "name", "cost_iva", "description", 
   "provider__name", "company__name", "brand", "maker", "cost", "suggested_price",
   "sku", "barcode", "stock", "width", "height", "depth", "weight", "shipping_width",
   "shipping_height", "shipping_depth", "shipping_weight", "deleted_at")

Comment: @Fragoso fantástico. Si marcas la respuesta como la correcta te lo agradecería :)

Answer (score -1):

Poque no creas un Custom managers, con la consulta que necesitas?

[Aqui esta un ejemplo de la documentación oficial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/)
    from django.db import models

```
    from djando.db import models
    class PollManager(models.Manager):
        def with_counts(self):
            from django.db import connection
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("""
                    SELECT p.id, p.question, p.poll_date, COUNT(*)
                    FROM polls_opinionpoll p, polls_response r
                    WHERE p.id = r.poll_id
                    GROUP BY p.id, p.question, p.poll_date
                    ORDER BY p.poll_date DESC""")
                result_list = []
                for row in cursor.fetchall():
                    p = self.model(id=row[0], question=row[1], poll_date=row[2])
                    p.num_responses = row[3]
                    result_list.append(p)
            return result_list

    class OpinionPoll(models.Model):
        question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        poll_date = models.DateField()
        objects = PollManager()
```